# Links with ID's or names

Tags: php, html, web, hyperlink

When building websites, should my links make use of ID's or page names?

For example, when you've got a website that allows user input. A user can make a profile, every profile gets an id.
Should the link look like "http://mywebsite.com/profiles/1" (where 1 stands for the profile id) or like "http://mywebsite.com/profiles/name"  ?

edit: this example applies for an mvc framework where 'profiles' would be the controller and "name" or "1" the parameter

Of course, working with ID's is easier because of possible duplicate names and stuff. That is the reason why I have always used ID's in the past.

However, somebody told me that I should NEVER use ID's because of SEO. He said companies would never allow a website with ID's in links. Is this true?

Comment: what if you have two "John Smith" profiles. I would recommend some sort of unique identifier `ex: /profiles/john-smith-123`.

Comment: A url provides information about it's content (usually), for example "MyCompany/store/food/pizza" - it's better to read and remember, and it provides keywords (for the search engines). So yes, in terms of SEO people expect that it is a lot better (but who knows how it really works..).

I would also recommend you to use names and combine them with IDs where you could get in trouble with duplicate names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SEO and for people to easily remember the links names would be better . Each ID would be linked with a name and the names are unique at sign up we make sure that each user selects a unique name . In Facebook each profile has a unique username and each username is linked to a id .In database we store the ID , Username , other details like name,age etc.